# Keep getting Java exception: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I keep getting this same exception when I compile. Can anyone explain why I keep getting this error and what it means or what I need to do?
I would like to know what I am doing wrong for future references.

```
public static void Second()
{
  int n = stringList.listSize();
  for(int i=0; i<n-1; i=i+2)
  {
    System.out.println(stringList.retrieveAt(i) + " " + stringList.retrieveAt(i+1));
  }
}
public static void Display()throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
  Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\DataFile.txt")); 
  StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(infile.nextLine());
  StringElement str = new StringElement();

  while(infile.hasNext())
  {
    str.setString(token.nextToken());
    stringList.insert(str);
  }
  stringList.print();
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
        at Programmmmmm.Display(Programmmmmm.java:121)
        at Programmmmmm.main(Programmmmmm.java:67)
```

Comment: It's not a compile error, it's a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

You're crossing the streams.

You're looping over the `Scanner`, but checking `nextToken()` on the `StringTokenizer`.

You aren't following the Sun Java coding standards: method names should start with a lower case letter.

That one method is doing far too much:

1. Reading a hard coded file path.
2. Tokenizing each line
3. Printing a list of strings.

Bad idea.

Try something more like this:

```
public static List<String> tokenizeTextFile(String path) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
  List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
  BufferedReader br = null;
  if (path != null && path.length() > 0) {
    try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
      String line;
      while ((line = br.nextLine()) != null) {
        String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String token : tokens) {
          words.add(token);  
        }
     } finally {
        close(br);  // add this method.
     }
  }
  return words;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `token.nextToken()` without checking whether there are in fact more tokens in `token`.

Instead of checking whether there `infile` has more elements, you should check whether `token` has more tokens.

Instead of

```
while (infile.hasNext()) { ...
```

You should do

```
while (token.hasMoreTokens()) { ...
```

See [Oracle's Java documentation on `StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) for more information and code examples.